# How to get the details of an error message in an Azure Data Factory pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, error-messaging

The last step of my pipeline in Azure Data Factory executes another pipeline with the flow in which there is a Notebook step. As part of my requirement I need to capture the details of the error messages when this step fails (to store it in the database).
[image]

However, the output of the last step does not provide this information, only the link to the other one. My challenge is that I can not modify the "internal" pipeline to get that data (we are interested in the URL of the error), I need to do it everything from the one I have created.

Unfortunately I have not been able to find any possible solution or docs to try to solve this. I'd appreciate any suggestion you can give me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any activity will have the output stored in the format as below.

```
@activity('*activityName*').output.*subfield1*.*subfield2*
```

To access the output incase of a failed activity, you can select **Add activity on** `failure stream` and use to set a variable.

However, in this scenario, since another pipeline is being executed, its output returned to the parent pipeline (`ExecutePipeline` activity) is just the Child `PipelineName` and `PipelineRunId`.

So let us utilize this PipelineRunId. Let us use the WebActivity to call a REST API **[Activity Runs - Query By Pipeline Run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activity-runs/query-by-pipeline-run)**

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/{factoryName}/pipelineruns/{runId}/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01
```

**1.** Get **PipelineRunId** from ExecutePipeline activity output and set to a variable.

[image]

[image]

**errorOutput:**    `@activity('Execute Pipeline').output.pipelineRunId`

[image]

**2.** Use this run id to dynamically form the url

**url:**    `https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/b83c1ed3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/myrg/providers/Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/ktestadf/pipelineruns/@{variables('pipelineRunId')}/queryActivityruns?api-version=2018-06-01`

[image]

**3.** Now prepare for the REST API call. Use the `url` already prepared. Set method POST, header and body.

[image]

Body of the request is a time range in which the querying pipeline ran. We shall set a 1 hour window before and after this call is being made dynamically.

**Method:** POST

**Header:** Content-Type: application/json

**Body:**    `{"lastUpdatedAfter":getPastTime(1, 'Hour'),"lastUpdatedBefore":getFutureTime(1, 'Hour')}`

**Authentication:**  If using MSI set Resource: `https://management.azure.com/`

**4.** Finally store that error message in another Array variable, from which you can parse the array and store to SQL sink as required.

[image]

here are its content.

```
{
    "name": "ErrorMsg",
    "value": [
        {
            "activityRunEnd": "2021-10-14T07:43:20.1291832Z",
            "activityName": "Notebook",
            "activityRunStart": "2021-10-14T07:43:18.3867797Z",
            "activityType": "DatabricksNotebook",
            "durationInMs": 1742,
            "retryAttempt": null,
            "error": {
                "errorCode": "2011",
                "message": "Caller was not found on any access policy in this key vault, secretName: databricksclientsecret, secretVersion: , vaultBaseUrl: https://ktestkeyvaults.vault.azure.net/. The error message is: The user, group or application 'name=Microsoft.DataFactory/factories;appid=3ecdccaf-xxxx-xxxx-8818-4f30b45856eb;oid=7ee614a9-xxxx-xxxx-a7cd-fbad1afc715b;iss=https://sts.windows.net/72f988bf-xxxx-41af-91ab-2d7cd011db47/' does not have secrets get permission on key vault 'ktestkeyvaultss;location=eastus'. For help resolving this issue, please see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2125287.",
                "failureType": "UserError",
                "target": "Notebook",
                "details": []
            },
            "activityRunId": "6c9519e1-b646-4d5b-a974-29bef371d7e5",
            "iterationHash": "",
            "input": {
                "notebookPath": "https://adb-7020907718042127.7.azuredatabricks.net/?o=7020907718041127#notebook/171399934287251/command/171399934287255"
            },
            "linkedServiceName": "",
            "output": {
                "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (Central US)",
                "executionDuration": 0,
                "durationInQueue": {
                    "integrationRuntimeQueue": 1
                },
                "billingReference": {
                    "activityType": "ExternalActivity",
                    "billableDuration": [
                        {
                            "meterType": "AzureIR",
                            "duration": 0.016666666666666666,
                            "unit": "Hours"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "userProperties": {},
            "pipelineName": "error2",
            "pipelineRunId": "6a717388-516e-46d7-883c-fdcf2d517bd8",
            "status": "Failed",
            "recoveryStatus": "None",
            "integrationRuntimeNames": [
                "defaultintegrationruntime"
            ],
            "executionDetails": {
                "integrationRuntime": [
                    {
                        "name": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime",
                        "type": "Managed",
                        "location": "Central US"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "id": "/SUBSCRIPTIONS/B83C2ED3-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-2B80A074C23F/RESOURCEGROUPS/myrg/PROVIDERS/MICROSOFT.DATAFACTORY/FACTORIES/KTESTADF/pipelineruns/6a717388-516e-46d7-883c-fdcf2d517bd8/activityruns/6c9519e1-b646-4d5b-a974-29bef371d7e5"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have a different error message, you would find the required URL similarly.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot for your invaluable help.

Comment: Glad I could be of help 

Answer (score 8):

```
@activity('activityname').Error.message
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Comment: Upvoting as this answer worked for me. Sometimes we can just get a hint from a short answer and apply the same and try it. In this case, this answer worked for me on the very first try.

Comment: worked for me as well!

Comment: I need to only capture only details part whereas above expression is giving me full error message. My error details contain some words in quotes like '}'.
Can you tell me how can I save only below part in SQL table:  'ERROR [42000] SQL compilation error:
syntax error line 3 at position 43 unexpected '"StatusCode"'.
syntax error line 3 at position 1,327 unexpected '}'.'

Answer (score 1):

Try to enclose your code in try-except blocks as mentioned here

[Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66667773/how-to-handle-exceptions-in-azure-databricks-notebooks)

Inside except block, You could also return the error message using

```
dbutils.notebook.exit(errmsg)
```

back to ADF and assign to variable like

```
@activity('Notebook1').output.runoutput
```

From the variable you can write to a table/file.

[Video](https://youtu.be/LHUGh5oLch8)

Comment: Hi. Amazing solution. I can not touch the notebooks code, but definitely I will propose it thanks to your video.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback