# azure data factory- capture copy activity error message in child pipeline from master pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

[i've updated my question with images, pls check and help me in fixing this issue]

1. i have created data flow - to log error details.
   parameter -> errorMessage_Child

[child dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONZwy.png)

2. created a pipeline to call above data flow (step 1), named as pl_ErrorLog.
   parameter -> errorMessage_Parent

[pipeline calling dataflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOEjy.png)

[passing parameter value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWZOc.png)

3. created another pipeline with a copy activity and called above pl_ErrorLog (step 2) pipeline (thru execute pipeline) during failure path for copy activity.
   parameter    -> errorMessage_Parent
   value passed -> @activity('Copy data1').output.errors[0].message

[parent pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8Kbq.png)

but my execute pipeline is getting failed with below error:-
*Job failed due to reason: The store configuration is not defined. This error is potentially caused by invalid parameter assignment in the pipeline.","Details":""*

Comment: Checkout this solution from a similar ask [How to get the details of an error message in an Azure Data Factory pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69567222/15969417)

Comment: Did you find a way around this ?

Comment: no, I tried , but couldn't able to achieve this.