# How to get inner pipeline error message as email in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, email, azure-logic-apps, azure-data-factory

Hello I am using Main Pipeline for many child pipelines. So when child pipeline is failing i am not getting detailed error. I have seen so many posts but there is no detailed explanation. Can anyone explain me in detailed with screenshots. Many thanks

Example:

Pipeline Name : pipeline3

pipelineRunId : 54678565782hjed217

Message: Operation on target ForEach1 failed: Activity failed because an inner activity failed

How to get the actual error

Updated question
[image]

=======================================================

[ErrorMsg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJNps.png)

I am getting error message as like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have answered a similar question already here [How to get the details of an error message in an Azure Data Factory pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69567222/15969417). please have a look and let me know if any queries.

Comment: I am getting error while following that procedure

Comment: can you explain in detail, or update the question

Comment: I have updated the question please check

Comment: checking.. seems to be a config issue, can you show the `web activity` properties configured

Comment: Hey I have added screenshot of web acitivity and url

Comment: can you try with a different authentication and make sure there are no blockers or plugins active on the page in your browser

Comment: recheck your variable names match, chek the output at each activity step, see if they have right values as required

Comment: Not Sure what to do more.. I have tried all suggestions you have given

Comment: Still facing same issue


Invoking Web Activity failed with HttpStatusCode - '405 : MethodNotAllowed', message - ''